# Better way to gurantte initializing without error

Tags: ruby, mongodb

My initialization failed randomly.

What the better way to implement the init ?

> ```
> @client = Mongo::Client.new([ cfg["HOST"] ], :database => cfg["NAME"])
> ```

At least retry 10 times.

I found some solution like that

```
begin  
  coll.insert( { "counter" => i, "named" => "name#{i}" })
rescue Mongo::ConnectionFailure => ex  
  sleep(0.5)
  coll.insert( { "counter" => i, "named" => "name#{i}" })
end
```

Is there any elegant way to do so ? because I need to do similar init  in my project many places

Answer (score 0):

You could extract your connection logic to another method and do

```
connections = 0
while connections < 10 # or however many
  begin
    try_connecting
    break # only called when no error raised
  rescue Mongo::ConnectionFailure => ex
    connections += 1
    sleep(0.5)
  end
end
```

or maybe this:

```
def connect
  try_connecting
rescue Mongo::ConnectionFailure => ex
  fail = true
  sleep(0.5)
ensure
  return defined?(fail)
end

10.times { break unless connect }
```

Comment: can it be more elegant by `block` or `yield` ?

Comment: I don't think blocks are elegant. They are useful, and provide additional customisation, but they're not needed here. I've updated the answer with another attempt at this